# Where did the @property delcarations for the inbuilt services go?

Tags: plugin-development, documentation

I've noticed in a recent (not sure which exactly) version of Craft that the `@property-read` declarations for each of the inbuilt services have been dropped from `/craft/app/Craft.php`.

This means in PHP Storm, I no longer receive valuable code hints following a `craft()->` statement:

[image]

Is there a new way to access these hints in the recent version? Maybe I've missed something and accessing services via `craft()` is no longer the preferred method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad news is it's been a bug in PHPStorm since 9.0.1.

The good news is it's been fixed in the PHPStorm 11 [EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) and will be in the 11 final release.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28394

Comment: Interesting... Although those declarations have been removed either way, so where would the new hinting come from?

Comment: They haven't been removed from Craft itself: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/web/WebApp.php#L5

Comment: Ahh, the old `WebApp` class, of course.